# Console Calculator error java

Tags: java

So everything is working fine for this calculator besides for the askCalcChoice1. Since askCalcChoice1 is a string, I am calling it wrong (obviously). The error says it cannot convert string to int, as well as convert int to boolean. However, when i make the inputOperation as a string, it breaks the other 2 calls below askCalcChoice1. (it breaks displayRedults and askTwoValues because those are not strings). I do not know how to format askCalcChoice in order to call for this method that is written in another class wihtout breaking anything. askCalcChoice is written as a string which i pasted below the oopCalculator code. Is there any way and can someone please show me how to write that portion of that code in oopCalculator?

```
    int inputOperation; // user to choose the function
    askCalcChoice1 myAskCalcChoice1 = new askCalcChoice1(); 

    //menu becomes a complete string below
    String menu = "Welcome to Hilda Wu's Calculator\t\t"
            + "\n1. Addition\n"
            + "2. Subtraction\n"
            + "3. Multiplication\n"
            + "4. Division\n"
            + "5. Exit\n\n";
    calculatorCommands.pickNewSymbol(menu); //complete menu will be picked up as a string and display
    calculatorCommands.putDownSymbol();

    while (inputOperation = myAskCalcChoice1.calcChoice()) { //this will call for myAskCalcChoice1 class
        calculatorCommands.pickNewSymbol("\n"); //pick up the class 
        calculatorCommands.putDownSymbol(); //display the class

        askTwoValues myAskTwoValues = new askTwoValues();           
        float[] myFloats = myAskTwoValues.inputFloats(inputOperation);


        displayResults myDisplayResults = new displayResults();
        float result = myDisplayResults.showResults(inputOperation, myFloats);

        String strFormat = "The answer is:  " + result + "\n\n"; //print out The answer is as a string
        calculatorCommands.pickNewSymbol(strFormat); //pick up string from above
        calculatorCommands.putDownSymbol(); //display string
        calculatorCommands.pickNewSymbol(menu); // pick up menu from the beginning of code, loop to calculator menu
        calculatorCommands.putDownSymbol(); //display menu as loop
    }
    calculatorCommands.pickNewSymbol("\nThank you for using Hilda Wu's Calculator\n"); //when user choose to exit calculator
    calculatorCommands.putDownSymbol();
}






String calcChoice() {
    String input;
    do { //do loop will continue to run until user enters correct response
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5, A for Addition, S for Subtraction, M for Multiplication, or D for Division, or X for Exit: ");
        try { 
            input = readInput.nextLine(); //user will enter a response
            if (input.equals("A") || input.equals("S") || input.equals("M") || input.equals("D") || input.equals("X")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break; //user entered a character of A, S, M, or D
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(input) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(input) <= 5) { 
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break; //user entered a number between 1 and 5
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid choice, please try again.");
            }
            continue;
        }
        catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Try again.");
            continue; // loop will continue until correct answer is found
        }
    } while (true);
    return input;
}
```

}

Comment: I missed the question.

Comment: Where is the problem statement and where are you stuck and need help?

Comment: The problem is that I am getting an undefined error here  in the main calculator program. I am having trouble calling the switch method from the bottom snippet of code. Don't know how to format the statement to make it call for the switch method.askCalcChoice1 myAskCalcChoice1 = new askCalcChoice1(); while ((inputOperation = myAskCalcChoice1.userInput()) != 5)

Comment: Java is pretty good about telling you the error.  What kind of error did Java give you?

Comment: Ok then that is what you should ask for help with. Not alot of <broken-code-on-the-same-line-as-if-stackoverflow-members-are-bots-able-to-read-anything-written-on-one-line>. Tell us more about this _undefined error_. Is it an exception of some sort? If so, please include the stacktrace etc.

Comment: the method userInput() is undefined for the type askCalcChoice1. thats the error i'm receiving but i don't understand what it means. I'm very new to this and would like to know how i can format that line in order for it to call for the switch method i wrote.

Comment: We need to get some information regarding the askCalcChoice1 class. Does it contain a method named userInput()? Also, class names should always start with capital letter and not have integers. In this case, askCalcChoice1 should become AskCalcChoice. Rather name the instances of the class askCalcChoice1, askCalcChoice2 etc.

Comment: uh oh i realize i really messed up and pasted something else. I edited it to make sure i got all the correct code in now. Sorry guys. i'm in a bit of a panic since i've been looking at this code for a few days and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you are calling showResults with two arguments:
int choice 
and 
float [] f

Choice is never used. 
You use input variable instead in your switch but on default you return the error showing  choice.

Better pass choice as an argument in the function and be sure it is char and not other type.

Also this is not the form of a good stated question. I will not rate it down but please remake it so the whole code is correctly shown. I can not make sense of it easily. I might misunderstood it already. Please do not add comments between, be sure you have correct indentation and you got all the code in.
If you need to comment do it afterwards. It's not very complicated, just show us the code and ask what is wrong later ;)

If choice was meant to pass in the switch... then do it, but not as int but as char.